# Can I use two email addresses for MFA using custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I would just like to know, can we use two email addresses (provision for alternate email address) for Multi-factor authentication in custom policies with Azure Active Directory B2C just like two phone numbers. Is it possible to do that?

Any help would be appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Just learned from Microsoft Azure Support, it is not possible to use two email addresses for MFA in B2C.

Via built-in user flow or custom policy, only one phone number or [two phone numbers](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-add-secondarymfa)  is used for MFA. Please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-multi-factor-authentication).

If you need this feature in Azure AD B2C, you could post your idea on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Hi  @Allen thanks for your response. Could you please double check with the support team as i suspect only MFA with 2 email addresses is not possible but MFA with 2 phone numbers is possible via custom policies.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava I have reconfirmed that only 2 phone numbers is possible. It's not supported to use 2 emails currently.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava Have updated the answer. If it's helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MFA with 2 phone numbers sample [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-add-secondarymfa)

I am not aware of two email addresses being possible for OTP delivery.

Comment: thanks for the information. If there is no way of using 2 email addresses then why there is an option of providing an alternate email address when I go to the ADB2C tenant from azure portal under the section of Authentication Methods?

Comment: Because at this point you are utilising the underlying AADs feature set which AAD B2C depends on. And AAD has always provided this entry of alternate email address. As far as I know it’s not possible to surface 2 emails in a B2C user journey for OTP delivery.

Comment: Potentially this is possible with display controls

Comment: With display controls how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you can use [display controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-controls) see the example how to implement a [custom validation email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email), you can add display controls to validate mobile or email, as many as you want.

If you want sign in with both, you must to add it in the signinnames. i.e. signInNames.emailAddress1, signInNames.emailAddress2 ....

look the TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" in the TrustFrameworkBase, (I recommend later override it in the Trust Framework Extensions)

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
......
     <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress1" />
     <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress2" />
```